# Fixing invalid DNS records for mail server with SSL certificate

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl, email-server, mx-record, cname-record

Ok, so the question name is a bit weird but I wasn't quite sure how to word it. I have a machine with the hostname `foo.example.com` with an SSL certificate for the domain `mail.example.com`. I have also have the following DNS records for `example.com`:

```
A     foo.example.com  12.34.56.78
CNAME mail.example.com foo.example.com
MX    mail.example.com
```

Now I have recently learnt that the [RFC 2181 (section 10.3)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2181#section-10.3) states that the value of an MX record "must not be an alias".

My first attempt to fixing this would be to change the value of the MX record to `foo.example.com`, however this would cause problems as the name on the certificate is `mail.example.com` and I can not presently afford the expense of purchasing a new certificate.

My second attempt would be to add an A record for `mail.example.com` to point to `12.34.56.78` but the problem here is that the hostname provided by the SMTP server (Postfix) would not match the domain in the MX record and this may cause problems with some mail clients. Also, the reverse DNS record would not match.

Unfortunately changing the hostname of the machine itself to `mail.example.com` isn't an option as it is used for other things that use the other hostname.

Is there any other solution to this that I haven't thought of? Oddly enough it seems to have worked quite fine for the past year or so but as my configuring is actually invalid I'd like to correct it in case it is causing issues somewhere.

Comment: I believe this should be a Postfix question on "How to setup Postfix to use hostname different from the machine hostname". This is because you should be able to tell your mail server, which domain should it represent without changing DNS. So the correct way to go is to setup A record for mail.example.com to point to your IP and change Postfix settings.

Comment: Ah right. I didn't think of that, that should be fairly straightforward. Would it matter that the reverse DNS record would not match?

Comment: With mail server you always want make sure that the PTR record points to that mail.example.com. Some (target) systems require the PTR record to start with things like "smtp", "mail", "mx". So "foo.example.com" is not a good PTR record.

Comment: Mmm, that's potentially a problem as the machine is primarily `foo.example.com` and it wouldn't make logical sense for it's PTR record to say `mail.example.com`. Is it documented anywhere that this is a requirement?

Comment: We normally set our records as follows: MX[example.com]=mail.example.com, A[mail.example.com]=12.34.56.78,PTR[12.34.56.78]=mail.example.com  this turned out to be the best settings for mail server for us. There is no problem that the primary name of the machine is foo.example.com

Comment: At this point I'm not convinced it is necessary. I did a quick look at Apple, Google and Microsoft's DNS records and none of their PTR records matched the A records for their mail servers so I think I'm fine with not changing mine. If you'd like to put your first comment as an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: can you not have below:
A mail.example.com xx.xx.xx.xx 
CNAME foo.example.com mail.example.com
PTR xx.xx.xx.xx mail.example.com

Comment: In theory yes, but the PTR record is supposed to be "the canonical name" for the IP address, and in my case `foo.example.com` is the canonical address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, an MX should not point to a CNAME. In this case simply make another A record for mail.example.com:

```
 A     foo.example.com  12.34.56.78
 A     mail.example.com 12.34.56.78
 MX    mail.example.com
```

Since the certificate is for mail.example.com it thus matches the name used for connection and thus the certificate can be successfully validated. The PTR record should point back to `mail.example.com` to play well with spam filters.

Comment: The PTR record for 12.34.56.78 should return `mail.example.com` if you are sending email from this server. This will allow rDNS (reverse DNS) validation.

Comment: @BillThor: you are right, they might be relevant for SPF or spam filters. Updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: As mentioned in my comment above, I'd prefer not to update my PTR record as such as `mail.example.com` is "the canonical name" for the IP address. Furthermore, none of Apple, Google, Microsoft, or StackOverflow have such a PTR record so I don't think it will be a problem.

Comment: @DanielGibbs: the PTR records might be used by spam filters to adjust the spam level, see http://www.mxpolice.com/email-security/importance-of-ptr-records-for-reliable-mail-delivery/.

Comment: @DanielGibbs  rDNS validation passes for Google, Apple, Microsoft and StackOverflow.  Microsoft has a problem getting their servers to identify themselves by the name in their PTR record. I gather stats and >99% of hosts sending me ham pass rDNS, and >90% identify themselves the name in the PTR record.  A few large server farms that trace back to Microsoft skew the last certificate.  Both failures get penalized in my spam filtering (and catch most spambots).  It is not necessary (or recommended) to change the hostname, just publish the MX name and related PTR.

Comment: I think I might be misunderstanding what's required here. When I looked up Google's mail server, the PTR record for the IP address that it points to does not match the name in the MX record, nor the name that the server provides when connected to over SMTP. Is this not what you are referring to?

Comment: @DanielGibbs: I would not say that it is required but only that it might be used by spam filters, especially if no other good methods are available. Looking at gmail they have SPF records which clearly indicate from which IP a mail can be sent, so any heuristics based on rDNS are not necessary.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Ah right. SPF records look interesting, I'll look into that, thanks.